# Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future<Map<String, dynamic>>'

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm dealing with an error that I'm pretty sure is rooted in incorrect asynchrony, because I dealt with it before by adding a missing `await` keyword.

The error occurs here:

```
Map<String, dynamic> data = await handleNoData();
```

The function trace is the following:

```
data =
    await dataManager.attemptGetData(state.userId, () async {
  await handleNoData(state);
});
```

I put it into `attemptGetData` using `async` and `await` because it needs to include the Flutter state variable; I don't want to pass the state through all the function calls.

`attemptGetData` then passes `handleNoData` further into `getData`:

```
var data = await getData(userId, handleNoData);
```

and `getData` finally passes it to `getDataFinal`:

```
data = await _procure.getDataFinal(userId, handleNoData)
```

this is where it is used as in the first line of code above:

```
Map<String, dynamic> data = await handleNoData();
```

To summarize, `attemptGetData` --> `getData` --> `getDataFinal`.

There is something wrong with the way I use `await` but I am at a loss. Any ideas where the error might lie?

The function definitions:

```
Future<Map<String, Map<String, dynamic>>> attemptGetData(
  String userId, Function handleNoData) async

Future<Map<String, Map<String, dynamic>>> getData(
  String userId, Function handleNoData) async

Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getDataFinal(
  String userId, Function handleNoData) async
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your code correctly, your `getDataFinal` tries to receive data from the `handleNoData` callback with the line `Map<String, dynamic> data = await handleNoData();`.

So that means your `handleNoData` callback must be a function that returns a `Future<Map<String, dynamic>>`

But in your most outer call, you write your callback like the following:

```
data =
    await dataManager.attemptGetData(state.userId, () async {
  await handleNoData(state);
  // return <String, dynamic>{"fixes" : "error"};
});
```

Here no Map<String, dynamic> is returned in your callback method. You instead only await some other method with the same name, but return nothing.

So this leads to the error displayed, because your inner call of the callback method receives no data.